# Sparse Matrix print from linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print out the sparse matrix from my linked list. That looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 6 0 0 0 
4 0 0 0 6 0
```

But for this, it just prints out 0 with the value inside.
Here's the codes.

```
    while (temp != NULL)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if ((row == (temp -> e).getRow()) && (col == (temp -> e).getCol()))
                cout << temp ->e.getValue();
            else
                cout << "0";
        }
            cout << endl;
    }


    temp = temp -> next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` and `j` are being incremented. Those are the values you need to check against.

You're comparing with `row` and `col` which are the max values and will never be reached.